# Step-by-step convergence of infinite product

Tags: real-analysis

total amateur here.  Is it true that if an infinite product is equal to some real number $x$ the infinite product converges to $x$?

Second question: What is the convergence test for an infinite product?  I know this website usually likes to give as little info as possible "to encourage self study" but if someone would use as an example an infinite product that converges, showing step by step the proof of convergence, then that would be exactly what I made this post for.  Thanks!  (I am not looking for hints at how to figure it out, I want step by step demonstration of an entire proof.)

Comment: If an infinite product is zero, then the product is usually said to *diverge* to zero. There's no such thing as "the" convergence test for an infinite product, any more than there is "the" convergence test for an infinite sum – unless you are just asking for the *definition* of convergence for an infniite product.

Comment: How do you test whether an infinite product conforms to the definition of convergence for an infinite product?  Please give an example.

Comment: Well, first step is to know the definition of convergence for an infinite product. Do you?

Comment: I don't know it.

Comment: OK: $\prod_1^{\infty}a_n$ converges to $L$ means $L\ne0$ and $\lim_{N\to\infty}\prod_1^Na_n=L$.

Comment: Ok.  Why is it not possible for an infinite product to converge to zero?  Is it simply because $L\neq0$ is part of the definition?  How about $\prod_{n=1}^\infty n-1$?  What is the meaning when they say, "This formula does not converge?"  My thinking is, "Who cares if it converges to zero when it is identically equal to zero?"  What is the fine nuance involved in asking, "Does it converge?"

Comment: There is a close relation between infinite products and infinite sums, namely, $\log\prod a_n=\sum\log a_n$. If the product is zero, then the sum is minus infinity. When an infinite sum is minus infinity, we say the sum diverges. So, for consistency, when the product is zero, we say the product diverges. Also, for infinite products of reals (and for the same reason), it's customary to require all the $a_n$ to be positive.

Comment: So, how are we doing now, Jonathan?

Comment: That log definition makes sense for why it can't converge to zero and you were very helpful, thank you.  I have another open question too, unrelated: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3001760/is-this-definiton-well-posed