# Is this definition well-posed?

Tags: real-analysis

I have this definition: "Let $R\in\mathbb{N}$ be called arbitrarily large if and only if

$$
\forall\quad x\in\mathbb{N}\quad\exists\quad R\in\mathbb{N}\quad:\quad x<R~~\text{''}
$$

When I wrote it, I was thinking $\forall$ meant "for any," but now I see that it means "for all."  (Probably why LaTeX symbol is called \forall.)  I think this definition makes sense and is well posed because $\mathbb{N}$ is an open set whose supremum is not in $\mathbb{N}$.
 Is this definition ok or is it problematic?  When I use, "for all" in my head I say, "Choose $x=R$, then is $R$ greater to itself?"  The answer must be no, but my intention in constructing the definition was that $R$ cannot be chosen and instead only exists as a concept.
 What I mean by that is if you take $x=R$ then I will say, "Which natural number is that?"  The counterpart will say its ten million and five," and then I would say, "That number does not have the requisite property to be called $R$ because it is less that ten million and six."

Is this definition ok or inherently stupid?

Comment: There is no such $R$. Whether you call it "for any" or "for all" is irrelevant to this point. You have 90% of a proof of this statement in your question. 

So yes, I suppose it's a perfectly valid definition, it's just that the first (and last interesting) theorem that you'll prove about it is "no natural number is arbitrarily large".

Comment: I see. I think I should replace the definition to say $x\leq R$.  What is your opinion on this modified definition?

Comment: Precisely the same, for precisely the same reason.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to construct an infinity in the natural numbers, where infinity is greater than all natural numbers. There's something called the [extended natural numbers](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/extended+natural+number), which describes exactly that.

Comment: I think this is what is what I was going for: $X=\{ x\in\mathbb{R}~~:~~n<x<\infty~~\forall~~ n\in\mathbb{N}  \}~~,\qquad\text{and}\qquad R=\inf X \nonumber$

Comment: The set in the comment immediately preceding this one, is empty. There is no real number that exceeds every natural number.

Comment: @user3482749 "There is no such R. Whether you call it "for any" or "for all" is irrelevant to this point."  My thinking with "for any" is this.  Consider any $n\in\mathbb{N}$.  Does there exist an element of $\mathbb{N}$ that is greater than $n$.  Yes there is.  Therefore: $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\exists x\in\mathbb{N}:x>n$.  This is the original theorem with the \forall symbol meaning "for any."  This is true in all cases.  There is always an x for an n.  "For any" is the operative condition where "for all" invokes the limit criterion cited as the error in the "for all" case.

Comment: Either this question has been edited, or I'm an idiot and have been misreading it entirely: I'm sure it had the "there exists" at the start.

Answer (score 4):

It's not really meaningful to speak about whether a single number is "arbitrarily large" or not.

What one does often speak of is things like "$P(x)$ holds for arbitrarily large $x$". That can be formalized as

> "$P(x)$ holds for **arbitarily large** $x$" means
>   $$ \forall n\in\mathbb N : \exists x>n : P(x) $$

-- in other words, no matter how large an $n$ you're thinking of, you can find an *even larger* $x$ with the property $P$.

A related notion is

> "$P(x)$ holds for all **sufficiently large** $x$" means
>   $$ \exists n\in\mathbb N : \forall x>n : P(x) $$

Note that both of these are claims about the property $P$. They don't say something about any particular number $n$ or $x$.

Comment: This is the best comment.  Thank you Henning!

Answer (score 1):

An issue nobody pointed out is that you define a property about a number $R$, but in your definition you quantify over $R$. This doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Such $R$ doesn't exists, we can refer to a sequence $a_n$ (that is a function $\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{R}$)  *arbitrarly large* for example when we deal with limits stating that

$$\forall R\in\mathbb{N} \quad \exists x\in\mathbb{N}\quad \forall n\ge x\quad a_n\ge R$$

and in that case we say that $a_n \to \infty$.

Comment: Thank you!  I think I should replace the definition to say $x\leq R$.  What is your opinion on this modified definition?

Comment: You definition is not well posed (that is it is not true). In the definition given here for the limit we can use both $a_n\ge R$ or $a_n> R$.

Comment: I think I will use this: $X=\{ x\in\mathbb{R}~~:~~n<x<\infty~~\forall~~ n\in\mathbb{N}  \}~~,\qquad\text{and}\qquad R=\inf X $

Answer (score 0):

According to your definition no natural number is arbitrary large so why are you trying to define something which you know it does not exist?

You may want to define the concept of a sequence diverging to infinity in which case you have a sequence $R_n$ which gets larger than any arbitrary number.

Comment: The issue was that did not even realize the implication that no such R exists until after I wrote it and ha it explained to me here!  This is the one I think I will use instead: $X=\{ x\in\mathbb{R}~~:~~n<x<\infty~~\forall~~ n\in\mathbb{N}  \}~~,\qquad\text{and}\qquad R=\inf X \nonumber$

Comment: The new definition in not very helpful either.Your set $X$ is an empty set because there is no real number larger than all natural numbers. You have added  "and R=inf X" where in case of the empty set the infimum is infinity and infinity is not a real number.

Comment: Actually, the topic of the paper I'm writing is precisely that there are real numbers larger than every natural number.  I have a draft with a serious error in it (the one I made this question about) and you can have look if you ignore the catastrophically wrong error in Def 1.3: http://www.vixra.org/abs/1811.0222

Comment: In your paper, you postulate the existence of a number greater than any real number. Then you claim there are real numbers greater than it. That is nonsense.